# How to change text colour for Text View?

Tags: ios, uitextview

Ive tried using:

```
    hintView.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];  



- (IBAction)secondHintq:(id)sender {

if(!btn2Pressed) {
    if((coins -10) >= 0){
        coins = coins -10;
        score = score -2;


coinsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",coins];
hintView.text = @"Type in text here 2";

 [_candletwo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"candle2_03.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        coinsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",coins];
        self.candlethree.hidden = NO;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];


        CGPoint center = [_candlethree center];
        center.x = 160;
        center.y = 70;
        [_candlethree setCenter:center];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        btn2Pressed = true;



    }
    else{
        //Show an alert that the user has not enough coins
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TITLE" message:@"MESSAGE" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"RETURN BUTTON" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
}
}
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Is hintView a UITextView? Is it nil? If the IBOutlet is not connected, you're code will simply message nil which does nothing.

Comment: Were you able to change text color?

Comment: No I was not able to change the text size or colour, even when though I've changed the outlet and connected it!

Comment: @JohnGray Could you provide some screenshots? Make sure that you connected to the correct textview?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try doing something like this:

```
[hintView setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Also make sure if you are using IB that the outlet is connected properly.

Comment: Yeah, I'm never going to make that mistake again thats for sure, I had the IBOutlet under interface and it was not connected! Never even thought of that, Never again though! thanks!

Comment: Hmm... where are you setting this? Just try to set this in your viewDidLoad and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

First Make Sure.

1. IBOutlet is connected properly.
2. Check UITextView Object
3. There is no any subview above hintView.

> -(void) viewDidLoad{
>
> ```
>  NSLog(@"%@",hintView); // returns nil
> ```
>
> }

Then With use of this

```
[hintView setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

OR

```
  hintView.textColor=[UIColor greenColor];
```

Comment: I replaced the whole thing

Comment: @JohnGray have you checked NSLog(@"%@",hintView); in your ViewDidLoad method

Comment: when i tick in the attributes inspector  - "selectable" it works but if I unstick it It won't allow me to edit the size or colour!

Comment: @Marhavir No I can't find that line!

Comment: @JohnGray see my updated answer i have put NSLog to check hintView object. it will show output on your console.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the size and font for a label, you can do so.

```
[yourLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"font name" size:18]];
```

You can put a label in your view and do so.

I think this works even for a `textView`

**Based on Edit**

For color

```
[yourtextView setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hintView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"yourFontName" size:777];
```

Source:

[UITextView reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html)

[UIFont reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIFont)

Edit: textColor should work also. Check if you are not overriding this somewhere (eg. in Storyboard)

Comment: I've got the text view on a View in storyboard!